# Scrape peekyou.com ( having POST METHOD)

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, python-requests

[Please see the output which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwM0a.png) I am trying to scrape [peekyou.com](https://peekyou.com) which is kind of peoples search engine. They use POST method of php.I am using **requests.post** method of requests library to scrape the results .

suppose a persons name is "john coasta" then the target url would be :
peekyou.com/john_coasta

```
import requests
import json


payload = { 'formdata' : {'md5': '4a9050a569e0f7d862b771926f7abc57',
             'asynchronous': 'true'}

}
req = requests.post('https://www.peekyou.com/shantanu_sharma',
                 data = payload,
                  headers={ 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
                           'referer': 'https://www.peekyou.com/shantanu_sharma',
                            'server':'Apache/2.4.33 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-freebsd mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141'


}
                   )
print(req.content)
```

although I am getting the full result in HTML form , the result which I am seeking for is encoded(*I need decoded o/p*) in the characters like :\n\t ( inside every HTML tag {***surprisingly this is the actual result***}).I didn't use POST requests frequently. Please provide me some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting!
I am getting html page which has lots of "\n\t\r"  characters in place of text which I am seeking for. I am getting this [https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwM0a.png]

Answer (score 0):

> the result which I am seeking for is encoded in the characters like :\n\t

maybe the response is blank becuase you are doing something wrong?
when i opened that site, I found that it uses a lot of Cookies,but you are not using any cookies.If you are sure that you are doing everything in correct way ,then use a tool like Chrome dev tools to see what happens after making this post requests (using the browser)
,see if the browser is decoding/encoding/sending cookies/etc.
Edit:You are getting Blank response ,as i think :it is not encoded,the server is sending you this because you are doing something wrong in your post request(according to something i faced before!)

Comment: I literally don't know how to decode this.If you know some other approach to scrap or to decode, kindly share.

Comment: AS i think: you will have to look at the returned pages(js/html or anything) and see what it is doing (encoding/decoding/etc) for me:this is difficult .but as i said you can use chrome dev tools.Check the edit

Comment: I already tried, and it's obvious that my above script has parameters from dev-tools.  Thanks!

Comment: If so,please take a look at the Cookies part,and if the browser is sending encoded data,If you can put the link of the page that sends this post request will be better

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1conc6u85YRc2p8QC-_JAfksH5OjbjzjZ/view?usp=sharing] I am getting this as an output

Comment: as i see ,the page is not encoded,simply you can write the output to an html file and open it with browser as the /n and /t u see are normal characters no encoding as i see