# How to scrape page with POST method with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to join together some pages that report Starlink constellation passages. As they are now, I need to access each single page manually, and cannot filter out according to time and visibility.

The base page is https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=50&lng=12&loc=Somewhere.

[Scrape peekyou.com ( having POST METHOD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239651/scrape-peekyou-com-having-post-method) gives me some hints, but not enough to go on my feet.

This is the GET code to scrape the first page (the last Starlink launch):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(r"https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=45.61&lng=15.312&loc=Somewhere&alt=0&tz=CET")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
table = str(soup.find_all("table", {"class": "standardTable"}))

df = pd.read_html(table)[0]

cols = "date satellite mag s_time s_altitude s_azimuth h_time h_altitude h_azimuth e_time e_altitude e_azimuth".split()
df.columns = cols

print(df)
```

The other pages are requested with a POST method, clicking on the dropdown list. Here stops my (shallow) knowledge about web scraping.

I see that the returned `res.text` contains the form data that I could use for the next request, but I have no idea of how to extract them:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=48.55&amp;lng=11.53&amp;loc=Somewhere&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=CET" id="aspnetForm">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="DprSo0lEG4wbQojWQ3ub7mILDflL+omP+KQ
.../>
...
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="9E5B71D1" />
<input type="hidden" name="utcOffset" id="utcOffset" value="7200000" />
...
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cph1$hidStartUtc" id="ctl00_cph1_hidStartUtc" value="637211090517289358" />
...
# and here is the dropdown list:
<select name="ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches" id="ctl00_cph1_ddlLaunches">
    <option selected="selected" value="2020019">Starlink 5, 18 March 2020 12:16</option>
    <option value="2020012">Starlink 4, 17 February 2020 15:06</option>
    <option value="2020006">Starlink 3, 29 January 2020 14:07</option>
    <option value="2020001">Starlink 2, 07 January 2020 02:19</option>
    <option value="2019074">Starlink 1, 11 November 2019 14:56</option>
    <option value="2019029">Starlink 0, 24 May 2019 02:30</option>
</select>
```

Could you please help me with a pointer to a possible solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `Scrapy` or `Selenium` for such a single page.

You can achieve your target using `requests` , `bs4` and `pandas`.

Now, Let's put the plan:

---

**1**. We will check the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) under your `browser` [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) and see what happens once we change the date.

[image]

- As you can see, we noticed a `POST` request has been made to the
  [host](https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=50&lng=12&loc=Somewhere)
  with multiple `Form data`.

  Q: **Why you were getting a response for your call to the url without
  passing POST data** ?

  A: Because the `host` is actually set a specific date from the `drop
  down` to be `static` which is `18 March 2020 12:16` as you can see once you open the url.

> Notes:

1. you don't need to parse the `HTML` and search for the table to read it with `Pandas` as you can do it in one call! as `pandas` have a function called `read_html` which will parse the `HTML` and read the `tables` for you as a list. which you can move between them with slicing `[]`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=50&lng=12&loc=Somewhere")[0]

print(df)
```

2. you don't need to use [raw string](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string) at all. `Python raw string treats backslash`()`as a literal character` which in some cases it's need to be passed to the `host`.

---

**2**. We will have a look on all `parameters` within the `Form data` and discard the empty values `""` and check which `values` is `filled`. Now if we refresh the page, we will notice there's some `values` is changed. So we will check the `HTML` source and see if we can found those `values`.

[image]

As you can see we have found the `parameters` with it's `values` within this part of previous `screen-shot`.

And Here's the values of the `important` part of `drop-down` option where we need to pass it to this `parameter` `ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches`.

### [image]

**3**. Now, we will need to make `GET` request with maintaining the `session` object to parse the `url` and collect all our required `parameters` `values` and then make a `post` request. while we will read it with `Pandas`.

- Q: **Why we didn't use Pandas directly to read the HTML table**?
  A: Because `Pandas` doesn't have an option to pass the `Form data`, so we used `requests` and passed the `Form data` by `data=` and then read the `content` by `read_html`.

And Finally we will save each table to `csv` file with it's name.

**Final Code**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        times = [item.get("value") for item in soup.findAll(
            "option", value=re.compile(r"\d{6}"))]
        vs = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        vsg = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get("value")
        ut = soup.find("input", id="ctl00_cph1_hidStartUtc").get("value")
        for time in times:
            data = {
                '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                '__LASTFOCUS': '',
                '__VIEWSTATE': vs,
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vsg,
                'utcOffset': '0',
                'ctl00$ddlCulture': 'en',
                'ctl00$cph1$hidStartUtc': ut,
                'ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches': time
            }
            r = req.post(url, data=data)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]
            df.to_csv(f"{time}.csv", index=False)


Main("https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=50&lng=12&loc=Somewhere")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer. I understood more reading it than with a lot of sparse tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

this will simulate the click to the next page, place the code inside a `scrapy` spider [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
import pandas as pd
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['heavens-above.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://heavens-above.com/StarlinkLaunchPasses.aspx?lat=45.61&lng=15.312&loc=Somewhere&alt=0&tz=CET"
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        #open_in_browser(response) see the response
        table=response.xpath('//table[@class="standardTable"]').extract_first()
        df = pd.read_html(table)
        #do what you want the df
        #going to next page
        to_post = response.urljoin(response.xpath('//form[@name="aspnetForm"]/@action').extract_first())
        data = {
          '__EVENTTARGET': '',
          '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
          '__LASTFOCUS': '',
          '__VIEWSTATE':response.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract_first(),
          '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':response.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]/@value').extract_first(),
          'utcOffset':response.xpath('//*[@id="utcOffset"]/@value').extract_first(),
          'ctl00$ddlCulture': 'en',
          'ctl00$cph1$hidStartUtc':response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cph1_hidStartUtc"]/@value').extract_first(),
          'ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches':response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches"]/@value').extract_first(),
          'ctl00$cph1$ddlLaunches':response.xpath('//option[@selected="selected"]/@value').extract()[-1],
          'ctl00$cph1$btnNext': '>',
          }
        yield scrapy.http.FormRequest(to_post,callback=self.parse,formdata=data,)
```

Comment: Thank you. I never used Scrapy and it is interesting indeed.

Comment: indeed it is, I prefer it than requests because I am used to XPath and  faster scraping