# Python post request to a form of a webpage does not return the same HTML that appears on the webpage

Tags: python-requests, python-3.7

I'm trying to do a post request from python to this page https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pu/ccid/paginas/vp_rentafija.aspx

```py
    import requests
    
    URL = "https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pu/ccid/paginas/vp_rentafija.aspx"
    
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'   
    }
    payload = {"cboFecProceso":"12/10/2022"}
    
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.post(URL,headers=headers,data=payload)
    
    print(response.text)
```

The page has a form with select tags and some hidden inputs. The only parameter i'm interested into change is "cboFecProceso".

The pages updates a table when you introduce the inputs and submit the form. **The problem is that when i send the post request the response is just the html without the table that is generated when you submit the form with the inputs.**

**Note**:

- The hidden inputs have default values that change every time page is loaded (i dont'n know if this is important)
- I checked the network devtools to check the "content-type", "user-agent" and also to see how parameters where written and there are params like "__EVENTTARGET, __LASTFOCUS,.." that have no values or big large text with random chars (these are the hidden inputs)

Please if i miss some detail that might be useful please let me know. I will be checking all  the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here [How to scrape page with POST method with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920163/how-to-scrape-page-with-post-method-with-python). If someone also face some kind of similar problem the idea is to literally fill the inputs including the hidden ones.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd 

URL = "https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pu/ccid/paginas/vp_rentafija.aspx" 

with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get(URL) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 

    vs = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
    vsg = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get("value")
    ev_val = soup.find("input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value")

    data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            '__VIEWSTATE': vs,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vsg,
            '__SCROLLPOSITIONX':'0',
            '__SCROLLPOSITIONY':'0',
            '__EVENTVALIDATION':ev_val,
            'cboFecProceso': '12/10/2022',
            'cboMoneda':'',
            'cboEmisor':'',
            'cboRating':'',
            'btnConsultar':"Consultar"
        }
    r = req.post(URL, data=data)
    print(r.text)
```

Also if there is a `<input type="button" value="abcde">` (a button) you also need to fill it (at least in my case)